# I want to change ViewController inside Tabbar by clicking on the table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, button

To do this, I tied table cell to a new ViewController and use the following code:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bctdg71quoc1ds4/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%2030.01.14%2C%2016%2019%2007.png

Everything works when table cell as I use Accessory Detail Disclosure.
But in this case, the transition is carried out only by clicking on the Detail button.
But I want to transition occurred by clicking on the entire item, not a button.
How to do it?

Screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cihiotpxp3wa67j/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-01-30%2016.08.06.png

Comment: First why would you post a screen shot of you code? why not use `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` instead. Please put some level of research in before asking a question

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, this tutorial will be helpful for you:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1